# Python - Turbo Gears setup

Tags: windows-10, python, virtualenv

I'm trying to setup a Turbogears enviroment for Python, following the guide here http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/turbogears/wiki20.html#wiki20

I'm stuck at the virtualenv tgnev step, having attempted the solution suggested in the exception message and a few other things and I need some pointers.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>virtualenv tgenv
Using base prefix 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python 3.5'
New python executable in tgenv\Scripts\python.exe
ERROR: The executable tgenv\Scripts\python.exe is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is 'c:\\windows\\syswow64\\tgenv' (should be 'c:\\windows\\system32\\tgenv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
Note: some Windows users have reported this error when they installed Python for "Only this user" or have multiple versions of Python installed. Copying the appropriate PythonXX.dll to the virtualenv Scripts/ directory may fix this problem.
```

I'm completely new to Python and virtualenv, so please don't assume I know anything!

Interestingly, system32\tgenv does not exist, but syswow64 does, so it looks like virtualenv is making a mistake?

Comment: Could you try reinstalling python, but when you are asked whether to install it for the whole system or for everyone, pick everyone?

Answer (score 0):

http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/turbogears/wiki20.html#wiki20

> This tutorial takes for granted that you have a working Python environment with **Python2.6 or Python2.7**, with pip installed and you have a working browser to look at the web application you are developing.

You have Python 3.5 - this may be the culprit. There are several differences that may cause python-scripts/programs aimed for the older version to malfunction.

---

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3 :

> Guido van Rossum (the original creator of the Python language) decided to clean up Python 2.x properly, with less regard for backwards compatibility than is the case for new releases in the 2.x range. The most drastic improvement is the better Unicode support (with all text strings being Unicode by default) as well as saner bytes/Unicode separation.
>
> Besides, several aspects of the core language (such as print and exec being statements, integers using floor division) have been adjusted to be easier for newcomers to learn and to be more consistent with the rest of the language, and old cruft has been removed (for example, all classes are now new-style, "range()" returns a memory efficient iterable, not a list as in 2.x).